# Facebook-PHP-SDK Getting friends list is very slow

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Using below code to get friend's list ,But its takes lot of time to give the result.How can I get the result quicker.Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
or is there any other way I can get  friends list?

```
try {
    $requestFriends = $fb->get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name&limit=100');
    $friends = $requestFriends->getGraphEdge();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

// if have more friends than 100 as we defined the limit above on line no. 68
if ($fb->next($friends)) {
    $allFriends = array();
    $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
    $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
    while ($friends = $fb->next($friends)) {
        $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
        $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
        }
    foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
    echo $key['name'] . "<br>"; 

    }
} else {
    $allFriends = $friends->asArray();
    $totalFriends = count($allFriends);
    $counter = 0; 
    foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
        echo $key['name'] . "<br>";
        $counter++;
    }
    echo $counter;

}
```

Comment: debug the code and find out if it´s the facebook api or your code that is slow. if it´s the facebook api...well, nothing you can do. what means "slow" to you anyway?

Comment: Why are you only getting 100 friends at a time? I don't know how fast that API call is, but I would guess that most of your time in this code is being spent waiting for that request to return. Can you increase the limit to 1000?

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut  Thanks alot,I changed the limit and littlebit of the code and its fast now:)

Comment: @luschn "slow" meaning its more than 2 min and yea now after the changes issue is resolved .

Comment: trying to get all friends at once is a bad idea anyway. better use a limit of 100 max and offer a button/link for the user to load the "next 100 friends".

Comment: You are not allowed to use `taggable_friends` to get a list of all friends for any other purpose than actually tagging people in OG stories. It is explicitly __not__ a “workaround” for the limitations Facebook has placed on access to a user’s friends.

Comment: Cbore Thanks for the info.So how can i get the list of all friends.I see only this example to get the result,is there any other way to get list of all friends?